# Silverlight 4 Business Application or ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, silverlight-4.0

Wondering whether it is advisable to develop web applications under the "Silverlight 4 Business Application" template or under the "ASP.NET MVC 2 web application" template.

In any case, what are the PROS and CONS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I think a web application is better off being developed using MVC2.  Silverlight has and is coming a long way, but to my knowledge, is largely still client-side (please correct me if wrong anyone).  As such, I think MVC2 is a better platform because you're leveraging your web server to process all the work and not bogging down processes client-side.  I liken this to why we do certain things server-side vs. in JQuery/Javascript.  It's mostly because the server has the speed, capacity and ability to process the user experience in the best way possible.
MVC2 has come a long way since MVC1.  I would definitely support use of MVC2 in any new ASP.NET web applications over webforms.  There are trade-offs, especially if you cut your teeth on Webforms like I did :)
Overall, best bet for the future is MVC2 as we're still seeing a lot of advances in Silverlight, and not sure it's finished growing.

HTH,
Sid

Comment: SidC, thanks for your answer. I just finished a siverlight 4 laboratory and it seemed I was doing the same things as a previous lab of MVC 2, the use of Windows Communication Foundation and WPF in SL4 was increased and the access to the server resources is getting easy.

Comment: That's great to hear.  I'll give SL4 another look, especially with WCF functionality.  Thanks:)